# How to retrieve info about image object

Tags: ios, image, image-processing, image-size, completionhandler

I already faced a similar problem with retrieving data from one method and using it into another. I tried to solve the problem using global variables. It didn't work, but I was suggested to use completion handler instead and it solved my problem.

I guess now the problem is similar, but I'm very new to iOS programming and haven't mastered this topic yet.

**So how can I retrieve width and height of the image object in the code below and use it to calculate the height of the thumbnail?**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
     ...
            // Create a datatask and pass in the request
            let datatask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response:NSURLResponse?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                    // Get a reference to the imageview element of the cell
                    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

                    // Create an **IMAGE Object** from the data and assign it into the imageview
                    imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)

                })

            })

            datatask.resume()
        }

        return cell

}
```

Here is how I calculate the height of the thumbnail for now:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        // Get the width of the screen to calculate the height of the thumbnail
        return self.view.frame.size.width / hardcodedThumbnailWidth * hardcodedThumbnailHeight
    }
```

I'd be super thankful if you help me with this!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the height and width of the image by two ways like

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image.png")

1.  let width1 = image.size.width
    let height1 = image.size.height

2. let width2 = CGImageGetWidth(image.CGImage)
   let height2 = CGImageGetHeight(image.CGImage)
```

Through this you can maintain width and height values globally and do needful calculations.